# Why does dmidecode show the memory type as "unknown"?

Tags: ram, dmidecode

I am trying to identify with `dmidecode` whether my computer has DDR3 or DDR4 memory. But, when I run it, it does not provide any information that would let me identify the installed memory. For memory type it provides:

```
Type: Unknown
```

Why is the type of memory "unknown"? How can I make it show the type of memory?

Answer (score 1):

[Quoting David Schwartz](https://superuser.com/a/377480/1203531):

> The dmidecode program gives you the DMI information as reported by the
> BIOS. It is as accurate as the BIOS makes it. [Inaccuracies are common](http://www.linuxtoday.com/infrastructure/2004113000626OSHWHL).

You will have to find a different way to identify your RAM. The most reliable one is to look at the hardware itself.

Other options:

- look for other clues in `sudo dmidecode --type memory` output, such as the part number, which you can further look up on the Internet;
- look up your PC or laptop specification at the manufacturer's website or in a third party database;
- look up your motherboard and check compatible RAM types;
- boot into your BIOS to check if it provides such information.